# How do we egrep a special chars when they are from command line?

Tags: bash, grep

To make it clear I give an example.

Suppose we want to write an atechnic-fridenly egrep in bash script, which means this guy does not know how to escape special chars and he will only pass what he wants to find.

For example, when he wants to find the occurrence of *it's* in an article, he uses

```
./myEgrep it's myArticle
```

instead of

```
./myEgrep it\'s myArticle**
```

How can we handle this in the script? Basically egrep cannot be given and understand a string containing special chars as human do.The hardest part is how to wrap the **$1** in **Xgrep $1 $myArticle** inside the script. I tried fgrep it would not work out either.

Comment: "*How can we handle this in the script?*" You don't, because the command line you've shown won't even run the script. The issue is with the shell, not grep. In fact `'` isn't even special in grep.

Comment: @gonda: Aside what melpomene said: You can use the `-f` option of `grep`, which is doing a literal match.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that the single quote is being handled by shell or bash, and it is actually stopping the command from executing until the user types in another single quote.
If the whole phrase had been presented in double quotes by the user, then they would not have need to escape the single quote, or any spaces, i.e.:

```
./myEgrep "it's" myArticle
```

I recon this is quite easy to explain to users, even the less savvy ones.

Then in the script file you need to again wrap the argument in double-quotes:

```
Xgrep "$1" "$myArticle"
```

Best practice in scripts is to almost always wrap your arguments in double quotes, as it preserves the spaces inside variables.

Of course, that then leaves the issue of how the user can inject double-quotes from the command-line. The easy answer for you is for them to use single quotes to wrap double quotes, but perhaps not for them; and what if they want to mix quotes?

Another option would be for you to process the input and convert whitespace to a regex for any length of any whitespace, and single quotes to a regex for all quotes, including unicode open/close quotes? Again, easy to explain to users. Any other scheme and you will be reinventing escape codes.

Answer (score 0):

`'` isn't the only issue. What if the user types `./myEgrep foo .* bar` or `./myEgrep foo $(rm *) bar` (don't try it!)? When someone calls a tool from the shell **they are in the shell** and so shell syntax and semantics apply.

If you want them to be able to call your command with any arguments and have that call mean something different than it would in the shell then you need to write a wrapper tool that sets up a limited/non-shell environment for them to work within, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/env bash
function myEgrep() {
    local re="$1"
    grep -E "$re" wherever
}

while IFS= read -r line; do
    cmd="${line%% *}"
    args="${line#* }"
    case $cmd in
    myEgrep ) myEgrep "$args" ;;
    esac
done
```

So your user executes the above script and can enter whatever commands you allow them to enter and can include any characters they like.